# MySQL / Python Connector - Problema insertando datos

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

Me estoy conectando a una base de datos con Python. Uso "MySQL / Python Connector". Todo bien, consigo crear con python las columnas. Tengo un csv con datos que quiero guardar en las distintas tablas.

Una de las tablas es "DOCUMENTS" (el nombre de la BBDD es "melt").

El CSV tiene 30 columnas. En la tabla "DOCUMENTS" habrá 3 columnas.El script para meter las filas de las columnas que me interesan es el siguiente:

El script que he usado es el siguiente (lo he sacado de la documentación y de una guía):

```
   for row in export:
        cursor1.execute("""
                   INSERT INTO DOCUMENTS(
                   Date, Headline, URL)
                   VALUES(%s,%s,%s)""",
                    (row[0], row[1], row[2]))
cnx.commit()
print("Done")
```

***El error, en concreto, me lo indica en la fila donde defino (row[0], row[1], etc.***

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

***A tener en cuenta: el csv (export.csv) tiene 30 columnas. No quiero importarlas todas, solo 3. ¿Puede tener algo que ver esto cuando pongo lo de (row[0], row[1], etc.? En mi script pongo de row[0] a row[3], pero no sé qué criterio tengo que seguir ni cómo debo hacerlo***

Muchas gracias de antemano, un saludo!!

***Edit***: He editado bastante la pregunta y he reducido el número de columnas a importar a fin de simplificar el código.

Comment: Verificaste si tienen valores las columnas del row?

Comment: En una vista rápida, estas insertando 26 columnas pero solo pasas 2 valores : `VALUES ('%s', '%s')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu error se genera en esta string:

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO DOCUMENTS(Date, Headline, URL, Opening Text, Hit Sentence, Source,Influencer, Country, Subregion, Language, Reach, Desktop Reach, Mobile Reach, Twitter Social Echo, Facebook Social Echo, Reddit Social Echo, AVE, Sentiment, Key Phrases, Input Name, Keywords, Body, Tipo_informacion, Pais_campaña, Cliente, Nombre_campaña, Enlace) VALUES ('%s', '%s');" % (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[18], row[19], row[20], row[21], row[22], row[23], row[24], row[25], row[26])
```

Por tomar un ejemplo estos campos generan el error: **Opening Text, Hit Sentence** revisalos como están en la base de datos dado que el nombre correcto puede ser **Opening_Text**, el espacio en blanco es el que genera el error.

Comment: Estas insertando 26 columnas pero solo pasas 2 valores: `VALUES ('%s', '%s')`?

Comment: yo estoy dando el error del sql, el otro tambien lo es. Dado que aunque agrege todas las columnas en **VALUES** el error va a continuar

Comment: Es cierto que eso también está mal, pero el error es de Python no de la sintaxis de SQL. De cualquier forma, me parece,  la pregunta es más un error tipográfico que otra cosa.

Comment: El problema son ambos, por que corrige el error de **python** y luego va a tener un error en **mysql**

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, pero entiende que estas respondiendo por un error que el autor  ni siguiera preguntó y no respondes por el error que sí plantea en su pregunta.  Si quieres agrega el comentario que te hice a tu respuesta par que al menos este más completa, pero en mi opinión es lo que podríamos considerar un "distracción"  al escribir el código, que bien podría terminar cerrada como error tipográfico.

Comment: Buenos días! Y gracias por las respuestas. Lo cierto es que soy nuevo con la sintaxis de SQL, por lo que cualquier corrección es bienvenida. El error del que habláis me es completamente desconocido. Voy a revisar ahora mismo el espacio en blanco, pero me da que no es ese el problema dado que en todos los lugares habidos las columnas son llamadas de la misma forma...

Comment: Actualizo pregunta, que creo que veo donde está el error, aunque no sé arreglarlo!!

Comment: @PatricioMoracho y DavElsanto, he editado la pregunta. Espero que sirva... Muchas gracias!